# Hibernate: ManytoOne - how many object?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I have database with many object (for example "Ad"), every Ad belongs to one "Category". This relationship is ManyToONe. I will fetch some Ads and by eager option I will get in every Ad reference to Category object. My question is: If I will get several Ads with same category, will be for each category created unique object or will all references point to 1 same object?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: I am just learning testing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ad1 and ad2 both belong to the same category c1 and are loaded in the same hibernate session, both will have a reference to the same Category object c1.

Comment: how about if 2 independent child objects are queried and both will have the parent in them..would they still be pointing to the same parent? you answer would be highly appreciated..thanks.

Comment: If they're loaded in the same session, yes.

Comment: same session? didn't get the point.. I am talking about 2 objects such as c1 is returned by a function and c2 is returned by another function. They both will be having a separate space in the memory and their parent object would still be same? If this is the case, hibernate should be really light but it has overheads of memory along with certain other benefits.. since you are 296k, your reply and knowledge will be really appreciated :) ..

Comment: To load entity instances from the database, you use a Hibernate Session object. Whatever the methods used to load the entities, if the methods both use the same Hibernate Session to load ad1 and ad2, ad1 and ad2 will have a reference to the same c1 object.